# How to move .NET libraries to a subdirectory?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to put all libraries (dll) used by my application to a subdirectory (let' say named "lib"). How to instruct assembly loader to look for referenced assemblies in that particular directory (which is a subdirectory of a directory, where main assembly exists)?

I assume it should be done by some settings in app.config, right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[probing paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(VS.80).aspx) in your app.config. To borrow the example from MSDN:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's it, I even remember using it once :}

Comment: note - semicolon delimiter is key - if a comma exists then the probing wont work.